# Override :hover of parent on child

Tags: css, hover

I have something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>Normal item</div>
    <div class="special">Special item</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to set the opacity to 50% when I hover over the div.parent, but I don't want this to effect the Special item.

I tried the following:

```
.parent:hover {
    opacity: 50%;
}
.special {
    opacity: 100% !important
}
```

But this doesn't work, is there someway to select that the .special children always have opacity: 100%?

EDIT:
I now tried the following

```
.parent:hover {
    opacity: 50%;
}

.parent:hover .special {
    color: white;
    opacity: 100% !important;
}
```

The Color changes to white, but the opacity isn't affected.

Comment: Which div in this is meant to be the ul?

Comment: @Light sorry none, I accidentally wrote ul instead of div.

Comment: That's not possible. If you say that an item hat only 50% opacity, all the children are affected by it. You can't revert it for subchildren because this is like a filter you lac on top of all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the opacity property you can change the color using rgba:

```css
.parent:hover {
   color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.special {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>Normal item</div>
    <div class="special">Special item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Target the child `div` elements when you hover the `.parent`, rather than the entire `div`

```css
.parent:hover > div {
    opacity: 50%;
}

.special {
    opacity: 100% !important
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div>Normal Item</div>
  <div class="special">Special item</div>
  <div>Normal Item</div>
</div>
```

You could also use `.not()`

```css
.parent:hover > div:not(.special) {
    opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div>Normal Item</div>
  <div class="special">Special item</div>
  <div>Normal Item</div>
</div>
```